# set class using state if else with react gets state of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to set a class dynamically depending on the pros i send to the component. Somehow i get the error " Cannot read property 'state' of undefined".
I guess that this doesn't exist when i try to set the class of the state as a class? Do i have to rebind it before i use it in the render of the component?

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("BUTTON")
        console.log(props);

        this.state = {
            class: "small-button"
        };

        props.options.map(function (option) {
            if (option.Description > 10) {
                this.setState({
                    class: "big-button"
                });
            }
        });
        console.log("STATE: " + this.state.class);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.options) {
            return (<div> {
                this.props.options.map(function (option) {
                    return <div className={ this.state.class === 'big-button' ? 'option-button big-button' : 'option-button small-button'} key={option.Id}> {option.Description}</div>
                })
            }
            </div>
            )
        } else {
            return <div>No options defined</div>
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Button;
```

Comment: its' a binding issue, use `arrow function`: `this.props.options.map( (option) =>  { .....` **one suggestion:** don't put logic inside `constructor` and don't do `setState` also, use lifecycle method for that. Put that logic inside `componentDidMount` method or `componentWillMount` method :)

Comment: Thanks but i'm super new to react, could you provide me with a bigger code example what you mean by arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a binding issue, you need to `bind` the function to use `this` keyword (correct context) inside that.

Use this:

```
render() {
        if (this.props.options) {
            return (<div> {
                this.props.options.map((option) => {
                    return <div className={ this.state.class === 'big-button' ? 'option-button big-button' : 'option-button small-button'} key={option.Id}> {option.Description}</div>
                })
            }
            </div> )
        } else {
            return <div>No options defined</div>
        }
    }
```

Check this answer for more detail on [**arrow function and this keyword**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/5185595)

**One Suggestion:** Don't put logic inside `constructor` and don't do `setState` also, use lifecycle method for that. Put that logic inside `componentDidMount` method or `componentWillMount` method.

Like this:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            class: "small-button"
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.options.forEach((option) => {
            if (option.Description > 10) {
                this.setState({
                    class: "big-button"
                });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.options) {
            return (
                <div> 
                {
                    this.props.options.map((option) => {
                        return <div className={ this.state.class === 'big-button' ? 'option-button big-button' : 'option-button small-button'} key={option.Id}> {option.Description}</div>
                    })
                }
                </div>
            )
        }else{
            return <div>No options defined</div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so          this.props.options.map((option) => { instead of this.props.options.map(function(option){
makes is bind the new state?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson  it will not `bind` the `state`, it will `bind` the `context` means if you don't bind, `this` keyword will not refer to `react class component` and `this.state` will be undefined, you code will also work if you just remove the `this` keyword inside map body, simply return a span it will not throw error.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson check the updated answer, attached a very useful link, it will help you to understand the role of this keyword.